# Having trouble getting the first value from a Haskell Tuple

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have a value that is in the form of `([(Int, Int, Int)], Int, Int)`

I need a function that would take data in the form of `([(Int, Int, Int)], Int, Int)` and return `[[(Int, Int, Int)]]`

So let's say my list is named `it`.
When I run `fst it`

I get this error

```
 * Couldn't match expected type `(a, b0)'
                  with actual type `([(Int, Int, Int)], Int, Int)'
    * In the first argument of `fst', namely `it'
      In the expression: fst it
      In an equation for `it': it = fst it
    * Relevant bindings include it :: a (bound at <interactive>:9:1)
```

I'm having trouble understanding what I'm doing wrong. Can someone help me out. I want to get the first value of `it` which is a list of lists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like the signature specifies, [**`fst :: (a, b) -> a`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fst) returns the *first* item of a **2**-tuple. So not a 3-tuple (or any *n*-tuple with *n ≠ 2*).

For 3-tuples (and higher), one typically uses pattern matching (for example in lambda-expressions). For example:

```
\(x, _, _) -> x
```

is a lambda-expression that obtain the first item of a 3-tuple.

Or you can define a function that does this pattern matching, for example:

```
fst3 :: (a, b, c) -> a
fst3 (x, _, _) = x
```

Comment: If the requirement is to have a function `foo:: ([(Int, Int, Int)], Int, Int) -> [[(Int, Int, Int)]]` would the method you provided still be correct?

Comment: @user1692517: it is a beginning to implement the funtion, but the type itself does not really makes much sense, since you wrap it twice in a list? Furthermore you will need to do some mapping.

Comment: Nvm i figured out how to keep the same function type. Thank you very much,

Comment: @user1692517: if you want to replicate things, this is the part to extact the first item yes. What you then have to do with the rest is of course another issue/aspect :)